# Overriding save method in a django proxy model

Tags: django

I am using a third party application and i wish to override the save() method of the original model to validate some data.

```
class CustomState(State):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('hellooo in save method of state')
        super(State, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However the code snippet above does not run.

Therefore my question is is there a way to override the save method of a model ? Or if thats not possible , is there a way to add in validation before the third party model instance is created?

Comment: A proxy model does not override anything of the original model. A proxy model "uses the original" table, and "attaches different behavior". If you thus make a `CustomState().save()`, then it will trigger this `.save()` method.

Comment: Ah i see , okay im getting a better understanding. However , the model creation is within the third party application by itself. As i don't wish to patch it is there a way to modify the behavior of the third party model when it is saved?

Comment: unless you use *monkey patching* (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching), no, and this is also a bit *risky* and inellegant.

Answer (score 2):

the issue has nothing to do with the fact that your Model is `proxy` but the wrong way how you call the parent `super().save()`:

```
class CustomState(State):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('hellooo in save method of state')

        # The wrong way to call super
        # super(State, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        super(CustomState, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

have a look at this tutorial, topic [A super() Deep Dive](https://realpython.com/python-super/#a-super-deep-dive)

Comment: If you are using Python3 - then you don't need the arguments to super() unless you are doing something very clever.